# xerox workcentre, address book, snmp

Tags: snmp, addressbook, network-printers

It seemd to me last year to find a web page where there are example of setting the workcentre 5755 public address book ( name, email ) using SNMP.

Now my google-fu is a little rusty, can you help me ?

Are there standardized OID to map public address book or are them custom xerox extensions ?

On the xerox website I cannot find any documentation.
I tried asking their tech supporto but they pointed me to the user' guide ...

Answer (score 0):

On the copier's webpage, if you click on address book after logging in as the administrator, there's usually (depending on the model) a link to download a .csv sample file.